# document.getElementId.value is not working, even if there is no syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have written exact code for document.getElementId.value,but still the textbox is not showing the expected value.
I am tring to calculate amount added with tax ,tax % is selected by using Select and amount from the textbox.

```
<select id="tax" name="tax" onchange="cal_tax(this.value)">
      <option value="0">0%</option>
      <option value="5">5%</option>
      <option value="12">12%</option>
      <option value="18">18%</option>
      <option value="28">28%</option>

    </select>

JS:
function cal_tax(taxc)
        {
            var tax=taxc*1;
            var          amount=parseInt("document.getElementById('amount').value");
            var total=(tax*amount/100)+ amount;
            document.getElementByID('taxdisplay').value=total;
        }
```

I even tried it with simple statements like

```
document.getElementByID('taxdisplay').value="any random text";
```

even this is not working, please help..I am stuck.

Comment: **1.** `parseInt(   document.getElementById('amount').value  )` without the quotes.

Comment: **2.** It's `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementByID`.

Comment: amazing, where you use it incorrectly in a string you get `getElementById` right .. but where you use it correctly and not as a string, you get `getElementByID` wrong ...what are the chances ... I'm amazed you    didn't try `"document.getElementByID('taxdisplay').value"=total;`

Comment: @JaromandaX haha I was wondering the same thing. But if your really look at it, it is actually a honest mistake: OP knows that `parseInt` expect a string so there you have **1.**. And since **1.** didn't work, OP started to doubt she wrote `document.getElementById` right, so there you have **2.** as debuging.

Comment: Nilam, JavaScript does not see a string like a piece of code, this means that `"alert(\"I'm a string.\")"` is never executed, while `alert("I'm not a string.")` is executed.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake I have made..I forgot to mention that I am a beginner..but I proved that..:D  Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

There is no id named "taxdisplay" in mentioned code. 
And correct object notation for getting elements by id would be in camelCase way i.e. getElementById('id_name').

Any DOM tree nodes like id or tagname or class are accessed in camelCase manner.

Google it out for camelCase and kebab-case.

Comment: I have not mentioned it here..but i have included it in my code.

Comment: Okay, I thought that this was all code that you got! Fine @NilamDhatrak